# Bloatware (¿ブロートウェア?), crapware (¿クラップウェア?), craplets (¿馬鹿?) in Japanese

Tags: english-to-japanese, terminology, connotation

Using Google Translate I get the following translation

English　　　　Japanese

"bloatware" ⇒「bloatware」

"crapware" ⇒「クラップウェア」

"craplets"　⇒「馬鹿」(whether that's the translation or they're just trying to tell me something I don't know).

How would I say these words in Japanese?

Would a Japanese person (someone with a basic knowledge of PC's) understand: It's the「ブロートウェア/クラップウェア/馬鹿」that's eating up all your resources. (Full sentence said in Japanese of course)

**EDIT**

Bloatware, crapware, craplets are pretty much all referring to the same thing (unwanted, RAM hogging, resource draining pre-installed crap software/apps), I'm not necessarily looking for a translation for each, but just a term/phrase that conveys a similar connotation.

Comment: I would be shocked if there were non-katakana words for these

Comment: @Blavius the whole reason I'm asking. lol

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the English words for those software :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is just me, but I do not know why you would use Google Translate for these or anything else for that matter.

"bloatware" = 「水{みず}ぶくれソフト」、「肥大化{ひだいか}ソフト」

"crapware" = 　「迷惑{めいわく}ソフト」、「くそソフト」

"craplets" =　「がらくたアプリケーション」、「がらくたソフト」

Comment: I have to start somewhere and googling "bloatware japanese" got me nowhere (If you google it now, this question has become the top search result. lol), I'm not sure any of those terms effective convey the (slang) meaning of "crap pre-installed software/apps"